# how to pass null value in sub query sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using two sub query. If I pass null or empty value its throwing exception

Exception message

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

My query

```
SELECT A.Product_Name AS [Product Name], A.Product_Id AS [Product Id], B.[DuplicateId]

FROM tb_new_product_Name_id AS A, 
(
SELECT COUNT(Product_id)+1 AS [Duplicate Id]
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
WHERE Product_id= (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
 ) AS B
 WHERE  Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' OR Product_Id like    '%'+@product_name_id+'%';
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part

```
WHERE Product_id= (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
```

to using IN instead

```
WHERE Product_id IN (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
```

Have a look at [IN (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery
>   or a list.

Comment: The in operator is used as explained above to determine if a value is in a given sub set or list.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a subquery should return only one record, but sometimes it can also return multiple records when used with operators like IN, NOT IN in the where clause. The query would be like,

```
SELECT COUNT(Product_id)+1 AS [Duplicate Id]
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
WHERE Product_id IN (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(Product_id)+1 AS [Duplicate Id]
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
WHERE Product_id= (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
 ) AS B
```

Use **Product_id IN** instead of **Product_id=**

because if you use

> Product_id = SELECT  Product_id
>                          FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
>                          WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id

it may return multiple values so use **Product_id IN**

so this is the correct query

```
SELECT COUNT(Product_id)+1 AS [Duplicate Id]
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate
WHERE Product_id IN (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
 ) AS B
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WHERE Product_id in (SELECT  Product_id
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
                 )
```

OR

```
WHERE Exists (SELECT  1
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                   WHERE  Product_Name=@product_name_id 
and tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate.Product_ID = tb_new_product_Name_id.Product_id
                 )
```

you can use depend on Query speed